# htaccess string query - redirect only from home but carry params

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

So I need to redirect when these certain params are in the url BUT ONLY from home...because we need to hold on to the params after the redirect happens, we do not want the redirect to be triggered over and over because the params are met. Please help, many thanks!

FROM: `/?color=blue&derps=many&db=true`

TO: `/path-to-direct-to?color=blue&derps=many&db=true`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^color=blue&derps=many&db=true
    RewriteRule ^ /path-to-direct-to [R=301,QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Try to add $ `RewriteRule ^$ /path-to-direct-to [R=301,QSA,L]`

Comment: @Talgat YEAH, THAT DID IT! Oh man, I was so close. Thanks so much for the help. Have a great day!